# Community Driven Advertising for Area 51 Proposals

Tags: feature-request, area-51, advertising, site-proposal

I propose a system similar to the "[Open Source Advertising"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/open-source-advertising), but for proposals on [Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/).

Many sites are stuck in limbo waiting to break into beta and could do with an injection of knowledgeable Stack Trilogy users.

It's preferable for proposals to "fail early" than hang around in limbo for months and months.

I suggest limiting the voting to proposals in the commitment stage and with >= 25% commitment.

In addition a separate vote for sites in public beta, or allowing the [Wordpress site](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/) to 'sponsor' the **[wordpress]** tag for example.

Answer (score 1):

I nominate [Application Security](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/8431/application-security) for the tag [security](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/security), [sql-injection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql-injection), [buffer-overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/buffer-overflow), [xss](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/xss), [xss-prevention](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/xss-prevention) and [csrf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/csrf).

Answer (score 0):

This makes no sense - any tag that that could be sponsored for a proposal would indicate that the proposal was a duplicate of the site that had that tag.

Comment: Are you seriously trying to convince me [Physics](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/1908/physics?referrer=Ho2q28uHijgN5QfMOt5KEg2) is a subset of SO because of the [~physic~](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/~physic~) tags? I dare you to post a question about theoretical electrodynamics there! :p

Comment: I disagree, while there can be overlap between the website, they usually bring some more in-depth question about the topic and have more expert watching those question. They are no duplicate. If i litterally follow what you just wrote, I could conclude Webmaster is a duplicate of SO with the tag [seo].

Answer (score 0):

It should work the same as [community-ads](/questions/tagged/community-ads).  Mods could open second topic for promoting non-open-source topic that could be of interest for developer's community. I'd like, for example, to promote [Expatriates](http://area51.stackexchange.com/ads/proposal/38732) proposal, because many developers are already working abroad, or are planning to do so. Surely they could benefit from the new site, but they may not be aware, that there's such proposal (or, that there's something like Area51).

Answer (score -2):

Nominating [Physics](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/1908/physics?referrer=Ho2q28uHijgN5QfMOt5KEg2) @ the [~physic~](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/~physic~) tags